# BPMN 2.0 - Roles

Tags: model, roles, bpmn

is there a way to model this?
I got 3 roles for 3 actions and role 1 can execute action 1. role 2 can execute action 2 and so on. 
Now i visualized a abstract process that contains all subprocesses. 
How can i name the lanes role for the abstract process?
I can't take role 1, because role one is there for action 1.
But i can also not take role 1/role2/role3 because they can't execute all roles. 
how to model this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create 3 lanes within the pool, one for each of the rules. First lane will be lane for role1 and will contain action1, second for role2 with action2 etc.

Your process flow can cross lanes, it only has to stay within the same pool.

Comment: and my end-node is placed where the last action is set?

Comment: If it's just end event not related to any action you can pave it in any lane and yes, usually they placed in the lane containing last action. If the end event contains some action like send message or broadcast signal it should be placed in a lane according to responsibility to take this action.